# MultiScaleImage (DeepZoom) control on Windows Phone 7 and local content

Tags: windows-phone-7, deepzoom

I was able to get the MultiScaleImage control to work in Windows Phone 7, but only with hosted content. I wasnt able to get it to work with local content that I had created.

Questions:

1. Is this possible (to display local content)?
2. If yes, are there any samples?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the MultiscaleImage control cannot consume a local image as input, because it expects an URI as an input, therefore the output of the Deepzoom Creator should be sitting on a server.

It would be nice to see a control similar to the MultiscaleImage that can consume local images or even one single image.

Comment: Yes, this would be a great idea to try. this sample would pack up a deepzoom image into a zip file and would extract to the isolatedstorage and use the raltive Uri to open this up on the phone.